# Software Profiling Tools

Tags: algorithm, profiling, big-o

Is there a software/profiling tool that given an algorithm and a set of inputs gives you the efficiency of the algorithm in terms of O-Notation

Comment: @InSane: Isn't cyclomatic complexity a completely different issue?

Comment: @Mike - you are absolutely right! My mind went off at a complete tangent there..thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big-O describes how the running time (and memory space) of an algorighm scales with inputs of different sizes, so such a tool would have to *not* accept a particular input.

If you can generate a range of inputs over a range of sizes, feed each input to the algorithm, measure the execution time (and/or memory size), and plot the result, you can then compare it against various possible big-O curves.

I don't know of any such general symbolic algorithm, and it sounds like a bit of an AI problem. Writing one would be a good exercise. There are probably algorithms which it could not analyze, but it might be able to analyze a useful subset.

Comment: I think it would be possible to get a glimpse of an algorithm's time complexity by running the program in question several times with different (big) inputs, measuring running time, then interpolating. The resulting graph would give an approximate representation of the function that represents the dependency between input size and running time.

Comment: @Grigory: Yes. (I think I said that.)

Comment: Ah, yes, I see. Seems like I didn't read your answer closely enough :)